# setOnItemClickListener for landscape mode

Tags: android, listview, landscape

My android app works on landscape mode. I have a listview that contains some items. The problem is the setOnItemClickListener is called only when I click the name of the item. I mean that if I select the row where is not the name of item the item is not select and setOnItemClickListener is not called. What should I do?

Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Here is my code :

```
MyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
        MyListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playlists));
        MyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                System.out.println("list touch "+ playlists[position]+" si id "+idPlaylist[position]);
                dialogwait = ProgressDialog.show(Playlist.this, "Loading...","Please wait..", true);

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPlaylist.class);
                i.putExtra("id",idPlaylist[position]);
                i.putExtra("timer",timerPlaylist[position]);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have onclicklistener in your name widget? try to get rid of it.

Comment: I don't have onclicklistener.I have only onitemclicklistener. I edited my question with my code.

Comment: i suspect android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 has a text view with width and height set to wrap_content

Comment: simple_list_item_1 is a file by default for listview. I didn't create it

Comment: Yes, the problem was at listview on xml : <ListView android:id="@+id/MyListView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` at ListView. This is the corect code for ListView :

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/MyListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are inflating some view for the items in the list setting width and height in xml layout to `fill_parent` could solve your problem,

well do not use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` cause you cannot change it...

you can do

```
MyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
        MyListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.mylistitem, playlists));
        MyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                System.out.println("list touch "+ playlists[position]+" si id "+idPlaylist[position]);
                dialogwait = ProgressDialog.show(Playlist.this, "Loading...","Please wait..", true);

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPlaylist.class);
                i.putExtra("id",idPlaylist[position]);
                i.putExtra("timer",timerPlaylist[position]);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

then R.layout.mylistitem can be

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/sometitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="some_height_you_want" />
```

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is the android layout how he can change it ?

Answer (score 0):

to use your textview rather than R.layout.simple_list_item_1 create your textview and put it in

MyListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.mytextview, playlists));